# My if else statement in C# is not working

Tags: c#

I'm really having trouble adding a condition that show message when user left the text box blank.I've tried every way that i know of to change it but it's not working at all.I have "5" textbox and hiding and showing them based on selected combobox item value for example if i selected firearm it should all five textbox and if i selected ammo then it should only show three textbox(1,2 and 3).And it should show message box warning me if i left a single textbox blank.

But the problem is during the ammo setting the message box kept showing up even though i have filled all of the textfield.Is there something wrong with my if else statement?

```
private void insertbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mysql = "";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Firearm")
    {
        mysql = "insert into Firearm(Fid,Fname,Ftype,Manufacturer,Price) values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";
    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Ammo")
    {
        mysql = "insert into Ammo(Aid,Atype,Coating,Metal) values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')";
    }

    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Ammo" && textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill all of the text fields");
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Firearm" && textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "" || textBox5.Text=="" )
    {           
         MessageBox.Show("Please Fill all of the text fields"); 
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbsource);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mysql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("New Data Inserted!");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!!!");
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`. Use parentheses correctly.

Comment: No error but it is not working the way i want it to be.The weird thing is when i deleted the firearm's if else condition then if condition in ammo works perfectly and it won't show messagebox when i filled all of the text field and again if put back the if statement for firearm then it kept showing me message box to fill all of the blank even though i did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is probably at this line:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Ammo" && 
   textBox1.Text == "" || 
   textBox2.Text == "" || 
   textBox3.Text == "")
```

I assume you want to say that is the value is "Ammo" and one of the text boxes are empty: (add another set of `()`

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Ammo" && 
   (textBox1.Text == "" || 
   textBox2.Text == "" || 
   textBox3.Text == ""))
```

And same for `else if` of "Firearm"

Comment: To be exact, the `MessageBox` is being shown after testing the second predicate (when `textBox4` and `textBox5` are both empty).

Comment: Thanks, but how did adding additional parenthesis change way statement works.

Comment: I mean why would it go to another if-statement to execute if the first condition is wrong in the first place.If that is true then the first condition should be rejected when condition is not "Firearm".

Comment: Because text boxes 2 or 3 were empty. Probably something like `if(ture && true || false || false)` - because you specified the `||` then if one of them is false...

Comment: @noeway Because of operator precedence, the second if statement is being evaluated as `if ((comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()=="Firearm" && textBox1.Text == "") || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "" || textBox5.Text=="") { ... }`. This is effectively `(false && true) || false || false || true || true` which evaluates as `true`.